# Get a particular month of previous year in Java

Tags: java

I want to get the previous year's APRIL month in milliseconds.

That is,if today is 28-01-2017 then I want to get 01-04-2016 in milliseconds. I tried a lot, but nothing worked for me. Can anyone help me?

Comment: So, give as your code, maybe we can help you :)

Comment: **Update:** `Calendar` and other flawed legacy date-time classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Calendar class to do this.

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); //Will given you current date
 c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);            //Decrement 1 year
 c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.APRIL); //Set Month to April
 c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);       //Set First date of that month 
 System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth
    .now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) )            // Returns a `YearMonth` object. Determines the current month as seen by the clock & calendar used by the people of that time zone.
    .minusYears( 1 )                                // Returns another `YearMonth` object. Immutable objects mean fresh new instead of altering original.
    .withMonth( Month.APRIL )                       // Returns yet another `YearMonth` object.
    .atDay( 1 )                                     // Returns a `LocalDate`.
    .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) )   // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .toInstant()                                    // Returns a `Instant` object.
    .toEpochMilli()                                 // Returns a `long` integer primitive value.
```

## *java.time*

In modern Java, use `LocalDate`, `YearMonth`, and `Month` classes. Never use legacy date-time classes such as terribly flawed `Calendar`.

To represent an entire month, use `YearMonth`.

```java
YearMonth aprilLastYear =
    YearMonth
        .now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
        .minusYears( 1 ) 
        .withMonth( Month.APRIL ) 
;
```

You said:

> in milliseconds

I will guess that you mean a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 as seen with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes seconds (1970-01-01T00:00Z).

```
LocalDate firstOfAprilLastYear = aprilLastYear.atDay( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime firstMomentOfAprilLastYearAsSeenInAuckland = 
    firstOfAprilLastYear.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ;
Instant instant = firstMomentOfAprilLastYearAsSeenInAuckland.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from time zone to an offset of zero (UTC).
long milliseconds = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocalDateTime`:

```
LocalDateTime.now().minusYears(1).getNano();
```

And if You want, You can get also: seconds, days, years, etc.

Comment: I cannot think of case where `LocalDateTime.now` is optimal. That class cannot represent the current moment as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.